# Convert graphic that is created on a specific control to Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net

How can I convert a graphic, created on a PictureBox, to Bitmap?

Comment: I am created a grafhic by MouseClick on a Pocture
box and it is an filled ellipse when a message or new window be show on PictureBox i loose the ellipse i want to convert it to Bitmat in order to it stay in first condition what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to draw directly on a `Bitmap` object by calling `Graphics.FromImage`, then set the `Bitmap` as the PictureBox's `Image`.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to create a Bitmap object:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `pictureBox1.Image.Save(..)`